# Resize Frame with jQuery

Tags: jquery, resize, frame

I'm searching for a possibility to resize `frames` (not `iframe`) by jQuery.
Unfortunatly I can't find any hint how to do it.

I'm truly grateful for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manipulate the frameset not the frame.

```
$('#frameset').attr("rows", newheight);
$('#frameset').attr("cols", newwidth);
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Just another hint is available [here](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/prop_frameset_cols.asp). It shows how to resize a frame by plain JavaScript.

I found this by searching "DOM frameset", as you'll want to change the frameset using its document object model representation. Unfortunately, the rows and colums are actually handled as plain string, uargh.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this jQuery UI Layout Plug-in
http://layout.jquery-dev.net/